# Disallow wiping via Profile Manager

Tags: ipad, profile-manager

Is it possible to prevent end users from remotely wiping their iPad in Apple Profile Manager?
I work at a school and I can foresee kids managing to steal each others passwords and remote wiping their iPad.

Comment: But you desire to avoid disabling Find my iPad?

Comment: The students seem to leak their school passwords more than their AppleID's. Also, the remote wiping in "Find My iPhone" is provided by Apple and installed by the user, so its their own fault if their iPad is wiped. On the other hand, the enrollment in Profile Manager is provided and required by our IT department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profile Manager has since been updated to allow the prevention of device wiping by users.